# Is there any way to configure the rebus DueMessageSender frequency?

Tags: c#, frequency, rebus

I have a external timeout manager configured with Rebus and that uses the SQL server. Right now it seems like the DueMessagesSender frequency is 1 sec. I dont need this much frequent checks as it would be a bit overhead on my database. Is there a configuration in rebus configurations where I can specify this frequency?

Below is the code of the external timeout manager.

```
services.AddRebus(configure => configure
          .Logging(l => l.Serilog(Log.Logger))
          .Transport(t => t.UseRabbitMq(queueConnectionString, queueName))
          .Timeouts(t => t.StoreInSqlServer(dbConnection, "RebusTimeouts", false)));
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes :) you simply do something like

```cs
Configure.With(...)
    .(...)
    .Options(o => {
        o.SetDueTimeoutsPollInteval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));
    })
    .Start();
```

in your timeout manager, and then it will poll every 5 s.